# Array of two text boxes in each row in tabular form, on blur some action

Tags: jquery, each

I have array of two textboxes in a table, on blur of one text box in a row I have to copy part of the text from one to other, similarly based on text typed in first text box I need to fill the second on blur. How do I do this in jQuery. I tried to use [.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) but does not seems to be working. Hope I am clear in my question, please help me resolving this.

I have the one name for each text box, mean finally I will get two arrays if I get them in java class.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post some sample HTML and perhaps some of the javascript that you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="text" id="txt1" />
<input type="text" id="txt2" />

$('#txt1').blur(function (){
 $('#txt2').val($(this).val());
});
```

if u need for more than one and if i understand u properly

```
<input type="text" class="txt1" />
<input type="text" class="txt2" />

$('.txt1').each(function (i,n){
 $(n).blur(function (){
    $('.txt2').eq(i).val($(n).val());
 });
});
```

Comment: I am looking for 2nd one as example. In the 2nd example what does that i and n mean?

Comment: `i` is incremental, or the index number, where as n i the Nth object , just like saying `$('div').eq(i)`

Comment: looks like i m progressing, but the problem I see here is when typing some value in txt1 the result is copied all the txt2 text boxes. In the html end I did not do any changes. Can you pl help did i do any mistake?

Comment: you are awesome.... thank you for your help.... I need to tweak it little bit for my usage, thanks again

Comment: may be one last question... how to subtring the txt1 value and then put it in txt2.

Comment: `$(n).val()` replace with `$(n).val().substring(from, to)` or look at this website if u need more help http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
$( '.yourTable input[name=textboxname]' ).blur( function() {

     var text = $( this ).val();

     //Crop/change the text here, whatever you want to do

     $( this ).parent().next( 'td' ).children( 'input[name=othertextboxname]' ).val( text );
} );
```

Since your textboxes got names, you can use them in your jQuery selector.
The rest is changing that text and traversing to the next textbox in the same row.

Comment: As I have multiple rows with same name, I don't know if above thing works. I will try.